# Try Catch, with event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, try-catch

I have a client that connects to my server, now with the following code the connection happens. But if the connection can't be made an event is created so my main program can show a message if it fails. But this event isn't triggered. How can I correct my code to make this happen?

Wrapper class for my Client Socket

```
public class ClientWrapper
{
    Socket clientSocket;
    public delegate void ErrorMessageHandler(string errorMsg);
    public event ErrorMessageHandler OnErrorRecieved;

    public ClientWrapper(IPAddress serverIP, int port)
    {
        clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(serverIP, port));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (OnErrorRecieved != null)
                OnErrorRecieved(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In my program code, Where the event is used

```
//Connect to Server
ClientWrapper clientSocket = new ClientWrapper(serverIP, port);

//Event trigger if client fails to connect to server

clientSocket.OnErrorRecieved += new ClientWrapper.ErrorMessageHandler(clientSocket_OnErrorRecieved);
```

And the method for the event

```
void clientSocket_OnErrorRecieved(string errorMsg)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No response from server. This can be caused if Server is offline or incorrect detail is provided.", "Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your constructor is already connecting, before you bound the event to it.
You should connect in a method other than the constructor:

```
public void Connect(IPAddress serverIP, int port)
{
    clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(serverIP, port));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (OnErrorRecieved != null)
                OnErrorRecieved(e.Message);
        }

}
```

And construct it this way.

```
ClientWrapper clientSocket = new ClientWrapper();
clientSocket.OnErrorRecieved += new clientWrapper.ErrorMessageHandler(clientSocket_OnErrorRecieved);
clientSocket.Connect(serverIP, port);
```

The event will only be triggered when it's bound before you connect.

Comment: @daJbot you can give him +1 too :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your event would've failed prior to you registering the event handler, as you raise it in the onstructor.

There are many options as to the approach you could try instead, such as passing the event handler to the constructor, so that it could subscribe it prior to being called, or breaking the connection code into a separate method, to give consumers a chance to subscribe to the error handler themselves.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the line

```
ClientWrapper clientSocket = new ClientWrapper(serverIP, port);
```

the constructor start to run. only when it ends then you connect the event

```
clientSocket.OnErrorRecieved += new ClientWrapper.ErrorMessageHandler(clientSocket_OnErrorRecieved);
```

you got 2 **Easy** possible ways to do it.

the first one is what Jeroen van Langen proposed.

the second is ask, in the constructor for delegate:

```
public ClientWrapper(IPAddress serverIP, int port, ErrorMessageHandler method)
{
    OnErrorRecieved += method;

    clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(serverIP, port));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (OnErrorRecieved != null)
            OnErrorRecieved(e.Message);
    }
}
```

also, please use `using` statement when using socket

Comment: On this construction i would suggest passing a class instead of a delegate. Same like to the Thread constructor. Like ClientWrapperInfo info = new ClientWrapperInfo(); info.ServerIP = ""; info.Port = 12345; info.OnErrorRecieved += new ClientWrapper.ErrorMessageHandler(clientSocket_OnErrorRecieved); ClientWrapper clientSocket = new ClientWrapper(info); This way you don't have to implement overloads on your constructor.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen i'm sorry but i can't read all this code in comment.... but just so you know it's perfectly normal to pass delegate, and you shouldn't pass entire class when you need just 1 parameter from it